# Working out mAh from current and time

Tags: current-measurement, amperage

If I know how many millamps I'm drawing, and also for how many milliseconds, how do I calculate this to mAh consumed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 1000 milliseconds in 1 second.
There are 3600 seconds in 1 hour.
That gives us 3600000 milliseconds in hour.

Consumed charge will be:

C = I * t / 3600000

where [C] is charge in [mAh] and [I] is current in [mA], and [t] is time in [ms]

If you want to calculate/estimate battery life - keep in mind, that nominal battery capacity applies to some nominal current / load. If your device draws small current - you will have more available capacity, and if current is large - you may get less mAh than nominal capacity.

Battery discharging with pulses may also affect "available" energy.

See battery documentation for more information.

Comment: I chose yours as it was easier to understand, having a formula. thanks.

Comment: Erm, 1 mA over one second equals 1mC, not 1C.

Comment: @Shamtam Right. I removed wrong information.

Answer (score 5):

That should be easy - each hour lasts 3.6 million milliseconds so each milliampere-hour contains 3.6 million *milliampere-milliseconds*. You have to multiply the current by the number of milliseconds which will give you milliampere-milliseconds and then divide that by 3.6 million to get milliampere-hours.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate the current over time and you have your charge. If you want that in mAh, divide by \$ 3.6 \cdot 10^6 \$